# Can't resolve Error: Segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to print out a vector of vertex pointers and I keep running into the Segmentation Fault (core dump) error. I tried dereferencing and then printing, but I found out that I was dereferencing an integer. So now I'm back at segmentation fault land. Any help would be much appreciated y'all! Thanks!

getAdjacentVertices() returns a vector, getWeight() returns an integer, and getAdjacentVertex() also returns an integer

```
vector<Vertex*> vertices (numVertices + 1);

for(int i=0;i<vertices.size();i++)
    {
        cout << "V" << i << ":  ";
        cout << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices().size();j++) ///ERROR IS HERE 
        {
            cout << "V" << vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices()[j].getAdjVertex() << " " << vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices()[j].getWeight() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have not made the pointers in the vector point to anything useful.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. As you are experiencing yourself, they are incredibly hard to use correctly.

Comment: All of the above are valid points, but how do I resolve this error???

Comment: Make the pointers in the vector point to something useful. Or don't store pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct `vertices`, make sure you initialize all of them to NULL.

```
vector<Vertex*> vertices (numVertices + 1, NULL);
```

In the `for` loop, check the value of the item in `vertices` before you use them.

```
for(int i=0;i<vertices.size();i++)
{
   cout << "V" << i << ":  ";
   cout << endl;
   if ( vertices[i] != NULL )
   {
     for(int j=0;j<vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices().size();j++) ///ERROR IS HERE 
     {
        cout << "V" << vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices()[j].getAdjVertex() << " " << vertices[i] -> getAdjacentVertices()[j].getWeight() << endl;
     }
   }
}
```